DEORE vs XT derralieus and other components
I've been told that XT is better than DEORE.
Is it only the weight is different or XT are better in other meaning ?
And some follow-up, if XT is better. Does a bike with a used XT is better than a new DEORE ?
(If yes, in which meaning or how I may feel the difference).
I plan to use a hard-tail XC bicycle for 2-3 hours cycling.

XT typically has more features than Deore, and more refined materials/constructions methods.
The differences between the two is hard to summarize, and depends on the generations you compare, as some technologies that were exclusive to XT have arrived after some time to Deore.
For derailleurs/shifters, XT shifters can move 4 gears up/2 gears down in one stroke, versus 3 up/1 down for Deore. XT uses bearings in some places where Deore uses bushings (jockey wheels, shifter axle),... The shifter contact points is rubberized on XT,... There are other differences, but that gives you an idea of the kind of difference that exist between the two ranges. These are mostly refinements, that are noticeable, but are probably only critical in competitive environments.
On the question old XT vs new Deore, it depends on your priorities and the generations you are comparing. If you want a single chainring, no discussion, new Deore (6100 not 5100). If you want multiple chainrings for the range, old XT is probably a better option (Deore with double chainrings have as much range as a 6100 Deore single chainring).

new Deore vs 7-8 years old XT ?

I invite you to check on shimano website, with the exact references of the products you want to compare. Current Deore is a range with 3 sub-ranges (4000, 5000, 6000), and XT was also offered in very different configurations. As I wrote, it depends also on your priorities.
